# Are these $3$ functions linearly independent or dependent?

Tags: calculus, independence

> Are the functions $f, g, h$ given below linearly independent? If they are not linearly independent, find a nontrivial solutions to the equations below:
>
> $$f(x)=e^{2x}- \cos(9x), \quad g(x)=e^{2x}+ \cos(9x), \quad h(x)= \cos(9x)$$

My take so far is that, I know these functions are not linearly independent (meaning this is surely dependent) by Wronskian (as the Wronskian determinant isn't equal to zero), but I have no idea how to find nontrivial solutions to this question. I think I should have an answer as follows:

$$ C_1(e^{2x}-\cos(9x)) + C_2(e^{2x}+\cos(9x)) + C_3\cos(9x) = 0 \qquad \text{ where } Cs \text{  are constant } $$

Could I get some help on finding those constants? I've tried $C_1$ as $-1$, $C_2$ as $1$ and $C_3$ as $0$ but that surely cannot be the answer.

Comment: In *Mathematica*, `Wronskian[{Exp[2 x] - Cos[9 x], Exp[2 x] + Cos[9 x], Cos[9 x]}, x]` yields $0$, showing that the three functions are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are a red herring. `;-)`

You basically have the vectors
$$
v-w,\quad v+w,\quad w
$$
in some vector space. These vectors belong to the subspace spanned by $v$ and $w$, which has dimension at most $2$. So a set of three vectors is necessarily linearly dependent.

How to find a nonzero linear combination is easy:
$$
a(v-w)+b(v+w)+cw=0
$$
gives
$$
(a+b)v+(-a+b+c)w=0
$$
so we can choose $b=-a$ and so $c=2a$. If we take $a=1$, we obtain $b=-1$ and $c=2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $C_1 = 1, C_2 = -1$ and $ C_3 = -2$.

Comment: may i ask how you could find those answers?

Comment: I choose $C_1 = 1$ (without any reason). Then I wanted to cancel the two exponential so I had to choose $C_2 = -1$. Then I was left with $-2\cos(9x)$ therefore I had to pick $C_3=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
f(x)\\
g(x)\\
h(x)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
-e^{2x}\\
\cos(9x)
\end{bmatrix}$$